# How to refresh a view's content in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I hate to ask what feels like such a basic question. However I have no idea how to do this and have been stuck for weeks.

I have a page of content that is loaded with data in my controller. On the view, I have some options to filter the view data with an apply button. Once that is clicked, I want the page to reload with the data filtered out, but without running the query again. I just want it to look at what it already has and hide the content that was filtered.

Can someone please give me a pointer in the right direction for this? The reason I do not want to query is because it is a very long call and can take up to 5 minutes to complete building the content.

Edit: Close to having it working, but the form data being sent to javascript is not up to date.

```
<div class="content">
<form id="form" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EpicType" class="label-control"></label>
            <select asp-for="EpicType" class="form-control" asp-items="@QueryModel.EpicTypes"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="EpicType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group" style="align-content: center; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5px;" ;>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0" onclick="javascript:filterResults('@QueryData.EpicType')">Apply</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click submit, I am not getting the newly user selected value for EpicType, I instead get whatever it was set to when the page was loaded. How do I get the data to save in the model before passing it to the javascript call?

```
function filterResults(epicType) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/refreshSummary',
        data: { epicType },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In a broad sense it sounds like you want to use JavaScript to update the page without reloading the whole page.  Ideally you'd be using AJAX to communicate back to the server-side operations where needed.  Then you can manipulate the page in the success callbacks for those AJAX operations.

Comment: @David I am a bit closer, but updated question with my issue now

Comment: This would explain why the page is reloading: `window.location.reload();`  In almost every case, reloading a page after an AJAX call is an anti-pattern.  The point of AJAX is to not have to reload the page.  Instead, what it sounds like you want to do is to update the page's content.  That's where you'd do that.  Changing element values, hiding/showing elements, etc.

Comment: @David I understand what you are saying, I just have no idea how to get all the model data to the javascript call. Seems a lot more complicated in Javascript then using backend code to get the job done. But with that said, I still would have the same problem. The epicType parameter is not the latest value of the model from the form data. How do I get it to send the proper value to the js call?

Comment: What I mean is, when the page loads, the default model value is "NA". I select a new value of say "Engineering" and click apply, but the call still gets "NA". Once the page refreshes, I can then click apply again and it has engineering set. But I need it set before the call

Comment: If the server-side code in `/Home/refreshSummary` produces new data then it should return that data as JSON.  Then the first argument to the `success` function would be that returned data.

Comment: @David I need the data being sent to refreshSummary to be new, not the other way. I am trying to pass the form data to the js call so that I can pass what the user wants to filter on to the rest call

Comment: So the data you want is in the `epicType` variable?  It's not clear what the problem is.  If the client is sending data to the server, then the client-side code has that data.  If the server is generating new data then it can return that data to the client.  In either case, the client-side code has the data it needs.  What's missing here?

Comment: Just noticed something in the updated code which may be the source of the confusion, and posted an answer below.  The transition from theoretical to practical in this question eluded me on the mobile app for a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click submit, I am not getting the newly user selected value for EpicType, I instead get whatever it was set to when the page was loaded.

That's because the code is explicitly defining that value here:

```
onclick="javascript:filterResults('@QueryData.EpicType')"
```

So let's say the `EpicType` is `5`, then what you have client-side is this:

```
onclick="javascript:filterResults('5')"
```

There's nothing dynamic about that.  It's hard-coded in the JavaScript to always be `5`.

Instead of passing the value there, just call the function:

```
onclick="javascript:filterResults()"
```

And within the function get the current value:

```
let epicType = $('#EpicType').val();
```

Note that I'm *guessing* on the `id` of the `<select>` element here.  You'll want to examine your client-side code (view page source in the browser) to see what the `<select>` ends up being.  This may also work:

```
let epicType = $('select[name="EpicType"]').val();
```

The point is, in the JavaScript code you need to fetch the currently selected value from the `<select>` element.  The server-side code has no way of knowing what that value is going to be when the page is rendering.

Comment: Thank you. As you can probably tell, I am not much of a web programmer. It has been a hard transition jumping straight into full fledged apps from WPF to ASP.

Comment: Thanks again, especially for the $('#EpicType').val(); part, helped me understand how to access things a little better. Was able to get rid of the rest call and do everything in JS instead by using data- tags to look up data.